# Where does WebMatrix save the site configuration?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, configuration, publishing, webmatrix

I have a website saved in Dropbox folder and I successfully worked on it for days without any problems with publishing. When I opened that site today in WebMatrix on another computer, I had to configure publishing settings again off course. I did that and tried to publish the site with only one file modified, but I was surprised when I saw all files in the publish dialog marked for upload.

One thing came to my mind - to copy site configuration from first to second computer so that second computer has information about already uploaded files and continues to publish just the modified ones, but I don't know if the site configuration is stored in file or registry or something else...

So, before I start digging I decided to ask the wise ones here :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it in following location:

**C:\Users\Username\Documents\IISExpress\config\PublishUI**

Answer (score 0):

When you try to make a new publish setting there is a link where you can say you want to import old settings. This looks for files with an extension called .PublishSettings or .XML, so I would start by searching your pc for files with that extension. I would imagine the .xml file would have your sites name in it's filename, so that is worth a shot as well :)

This should be enough. If not I am looking forward to hearing what others say or you can dig up yourself.